# Nvidia drivers for GTX 970

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I am long time (actually very long time) ATI video card user, and I've worked my way through all sort of issue with the drivers on Linux. So, now that I am an ATI *expert*, let's get down to business with Nvidia.

I've never worked with Nvidia cards under Linux, so I'm a bit unsure which drivers are best suited for my powerful GTX 970. The official ones from Nvidia site, or some 3rd party ones from ppa?

*Note: I don't plan on gaming in Ubuntu, I'm dual-booting to windows for that.*

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Ubuntu 15.10 here.

Comment: Guys the question isn't how do I install the drivers.  It is which version should I install for my card version.

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing that out for them :) I installed the additional drivers by the way, cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default version in the repos for 15.10 should do fine, I think 352.  I use that version with my 970m right now in 14.04 with the Wily kernel.  If you do have troubles though I wouldn't recommend downloading the drivers from the nvidia site as it does have bugs that crop up.

Instead you can try the new ppa https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

If you aren't planning on gaming honestly the open drivers will do great for most any task unless you are planning on something that requires the Nvidia closed source driver.

Comment: Great. I'll try then the default Additional Drivers.